# Nginx autoindex is blocking IO on listing files

Tags: linux, filesystems, http, nginx

I recently encountered this issue where,

1. I served a data path using auto-index, within it there is a directory with a LOT of files (I have a directory with 1228240 files on btrfs). Accessing an individual file is fine but listing files take 2 minutes.
2. When you try to access that path directly through an HTTP request, nginx freezes (yes, entirely freezes, all virtual hosts times out) until listing is done, that's 2 minutes of downtime.

However, I can't just disable auto-index because other paths depend on its json output.

Is there a way to resolve this issue? Or is it something that needs to be reported to nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also ran into this problem. It seems that autoindex does not use asynchronous file IO, so listing files blocks its event loop.

I played with the [aio directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#aio), but it doesn't change the blocking behavior of listing.

The only solution I found is to increase [worker processes](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_processes), so one worker process being blocked does not stop other worker processes from accepting requests. (Theoretically, any request being processed by that same blocked worker process will probably still time out.)

So, have something like this in your nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;
# or 16, or 64, more than the number of concurrent listing requests you may receive
```

Answer (score 1):

You might involve a caching proxy to get better results, as the list doesn't get recreated at every access.

But remind that displaying over 1 Mio file entries in web-layout is typically not usefull. (Drawing the folder view is a web layout). This is preferably a job for an ftp server and even there you should structure the files in sub folders. A full listing is several MB of data (probably at least 10MB and much more).

Another solution would be to provide the index via a database that could be searched for the content. Like this, not the whole list has to be transferred at each request. This database could also generate the JSON output that you require.